# Adding server hostname to each line of 'find' output

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I am in need of a listing of all files with a specific extension on a server.  I need it to show the server hostname, file size, and absolute path of the file.

```
echo $(hostname); find $(pwd) / -iname *.jpg -exec du -s {} \;
```

or

```
echo $(hostname); find $(pwd) / -iname *.jpg|xargs du -s
```

Almost get me there:
**joes_server**  
**5473   /home/joe/pics/sunset.jpg**  
**8522   /home/joe/pics/mountains.jpg**

I cannot figure out how to include the hostname on each line of the find output.  My attempts to add the hostname function into the xargs or -exec section result in errors because it tries to apply hostname to the find's output.

Is there a way to include the hostname on each line of the find output?

When looped through the many servers, I'd like to have an output like:  
**joes_server   5473   /home/joe/pics/sunset.jpg**  
**joes_server   8522   /home/joe/pics/mountains.jpg** 
**marys_server  5398   /home/mary/snapshots/background.jpg** 
**janes_server  9642   /home/jane/pictures/flowers.jpg**

Thanks

Comment: run the du output through sed/awk and have them put in the server name. you won't be able to do it BEFORE as your find would then be looking for `joes_server 5473/etc...` which won't exist.

Comment: It would be nice if `find` added a `-print` token for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find "$PWD" / -iname '*.jpg' -exec du -s {} + | sed "s/^/$(hostname): /"
```

(But, as @chepner notes below, having both `/` and `"$PWD"` is redundant; a find from `/` will eventually visit your current working directory, so you can leave off the `"$PWD"`. Or if you only want to look starting from where you are, just do `find "$PWD"` and leave off the `/`.)

Changes:

1. Use `$PWD` instead of `$(pwd)`  - no need to run a command when bash puts it in a parameter for you already
2. QUOTE!  QUOTE!  QUOTE!
3. Use `+` instead of `;` on the `find -exec` so that it will pass more than one file to each invocation of `du`; it's more efficient that way. If your version of `find` doesn't support `+` here, you can use `-print0 | xargs -0 du -s`.
4. Pipe the whole thing through `sed` to insert the hostname at the front of each line.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations along with your solution.  I know enough basic Linux to do my simple job.  My bad habits pointed out are what you get when someone doesn't know how to properly interpret the Google results they have cobbled together.

Comment: One of `"$PWD"` and `/` can be omitted; the former if you really want to search the entire file system, the latter if you really want to restrict the search to the current directory.

Comment: Any idea what the equivalent is with `perl -pe 's{^}{}g'`. I generally use perl instead of sed and would rather not add sed to my toolchain ;)

Comment: `perl -pe "s/^/$(hostname): /"` works, too. Or `perl -pe "s{^}{$(hostname): }"` if you prefer those delimiters. The shell is doing the work of turning `$(hostname)` into the actual hostname (which is why you need to use double quotes instead of single quotes); by the time `sed` or `perl` gets the string, it's all literal.